# How to create range of numbers with an increment in matlab

Tags: matlab

So, my problem was how to create a range of numbers with an increment?
for example i want a range from 0 to 3 but with an increment of 0.1, how can i generate that?
see picture below:

[image]

i tried using this code:

```
for ii=(0:3,0.1)
    display(ii)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach is: `0:0.1:3`

```
for i = 0:0.1:3
  display(i)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

you don`t need to use for loop to do it

`ii = 0:0.1:3`